# Webpack output only creates dist folder not dist.zip

Tags: webpack, build, webpack-4, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm new to webpack. I'm trying to build my Vue webpack cli project. when done the dist folder is created successfully. but I need to have a dist.zip folder which needs to be passed in the CICD pipeline on the go to next task. Is there any build config change required to make the output as zip package instead of mere folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a custom plugin like `webpack-zip-plugin`.

and then you can do something like

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new WebpackZipPlugin({
      frontShell: 'ls'
      initialFile: './dist',
      endPath: './buildPath',
      zipName: '[name].zip',
      behindShell: 'scp ***'
    })
  ]
}
```

For more details visit [here.](https://github.com/yyhappynice/webpack-zip-plugin)

Hope this helps.

Comment: does not work with webpack >=5